# Column filtering in DataSheet in Microsoft Access 2010 with joined tables does not work

Tags: ms-access

I have an access form with a Record Source that pulls information from two tables
`Select Rate.Prefix , Rate.Name, Provider.Carrier, Provider.Dest type,` 
`from Rate` 
`inner join Provider`
`on Rate.id = Provider.rateid`
now when i a generate a datasheet form, with the above four columns. **Prefix** and **Name** will do filtering, but **Carrier** and **Dest type** will not do any filtering.

The project is an Access Project file(.adp), that links directly to sql database tables.

refer the images below

Filtering using the **Name** Column

[image: Access before filtering, column that filtering works]

After Filtering the data looks like in the screen below

[image: After Filtering Name]

Now the screen below shows trying to filter using **Carrier** Column (this is before Filtering)

[image: Carrier Column before filtering]

Now after filtering, the data still remains the same as shown below

[image: Carrier Column after filtering]

Anyone with ideas if datasheet do not support filtering, on joined table columns?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the Access-specific DISTINCTROW predicate, so your SQL would be `SELECT DISTINCTROW...` -- this causes the database engine to resolve the unique rows on both sides of the join and can have almost magical effects in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion @David, i will try that and see what effect will that have

Comment: By the way i have created an access project (.adp) , which directly queries sql server database tables, and since DISTINCTROW is access-specific, this would not work

Comment: The question is about an ADP? That's crucial information and should have been included from the beginning. It's very hard to offer useful suggestions when such important details are omitted from the problem statement.

Comment: Sorry about i should have added that to the question, i will edit the question now

Comment: I believe that what you (and I) want is not possible, this is from the Access 2010 documentation:
_"Columns in datasheets and controls in forms and reports that are bound to expressions do not support filtering."_
I'm afraid the only way you can get it done is by creating a new query.

Comment: I've never used an adp. The filter on datasheet form based on join query works for me in Access 2010 using natural and calculated fields.